# Kairosdb not showing up in the list of datasources in Grafana 3

Tags: grafana, kairosdb

Grafana Kairosdb plugin integration, Kairosdb not showing up in the list of datasources in Grafana 3, even after dropping plugin into plugins directory. Has anyone has experience integrating Kairosdb with Grafana 3.0. There seems to be no errors at debug level in log files too.

Comment: Have you restarted Grafana after installing the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Go on your server where you installed grafana, open a shell :

- this will show you the plugin kairosdb

> grafana-cli plugins list-remote | grep kairos

- this will install the plugin kairosdb

> grafana-cli plugins install grafana-kairosdb-datasource

Do not forget to restart grafana !

> service grafana-server restart